# Error: Cannot find module './suns.png' when trying to get web page to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

MasonryPost
src/components/common/masonry-post.js:4

```
   import React from 'react'
   
   export default function  MasonryPost ({post, tagsOnTop}) {
   const style = {backgroundImage: `url("${require(`../../assets/images/${post.image}`)}")`};
     
     return (
   <a className="masonry-post overlay" style={style} href={post.link}>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

> How about `` url(`${require(../../assets/images/${post.image})}`)} ``
> I mena back tick > `

Comment: here's what happened next.   
./src/components/common/masonry-post.js
  Line 4:48:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  2 |    
  3 | export default function  MasonryPost ({post, tagsOnTop}) {
> 4 | const style = {backgroundImage: url(`${require(../../assets/images/${post.image})}`)};
    |                                                ^
  5 |   
  6 |   return (
  7 | <a className="masonry-post overlay" style={style} href={post.link}>